# Named Array Keys using .map() and .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to output inputs and their values into a div.  However, because I need to match the correct labels to the correct inputs, and some fields allow null values, I'm running into matching issues.  Using the following code to pull each label/input into an array, and then output:

```
var inputArr = $('input, select').map(function(){
    return "<p>" + $(this).val() + "</p>";
}).get()

var labelArr = $('label').map(function(){
  return "<p>" + $(this).text() + "</p>";
}).get()

function setValuesForConfirm() {
//Clear Div Contents                
  $("#test-output-1, #test-output").html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < labelArr.length; i++) {
    $("#test-output-1").append(labelArr[i]);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    $("#test-output").append(inputArr[i]);
  }
}
```

So if any of the input's are blank, the fields do not match the labels.

My question is, can I name the array keys to the field name or ID in JS using the .map() function as I am currently?

JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz9Vy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object using the inputs:

```
var formObj={};

$('input, select').each(function(){
    formObj[this.name]={val: this.value, labelText: $(this).prev('label').text()}; 

});
```

then when loop over object can throw together html

```
$.each(formObj, function(key, item){
    var labelHtml='<p>'+item.labelText+'</p>';
    var inputHtml='<p>Name: '+ key+', value: '+item.val+'</p>';
    /* do something with html*/
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Kudos

Comment: I assumed all labels are element previous to select or input. If not there are many ways to traverse

Comment: Right, based on your example I was able to pull the labels I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While what you have seems to work okay to me, `.map` creates an array and you can only have numeric ordinal keys in arrays in JavaScript, so you would need an object.

```
var inputArr = {};
$('input, select').each(function(){
    inputArr[$(this).attr('name')] = "<p>" + $(this).val() + "</p>";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mz9Vy/1/

Comment: Thanks.  While that makes sense, if you look at your JSFiddle, you can see that 2 is still outputting where 1 would if it had a value.  Pardon my density, but how would I best output the array value only if if it's key matches that of the label key? My thought would be to use a list for each element name/id.  Is there a more efficient way?